# Unable to get password reset url parameters in php

Tags: php

I have password reset url with `parameters(http://localhost/folder1/folder2/inc_resetPassword.php?token=1&tokenid=1)` in mail i am unable to get url parameters...

I attempted to use `print_r($_GET)` but it returns an empty array.

Comment: Show your code, what you have tried..

Comment: Make sure you are at that location.
Are you sending this link by email?

Comment: can you add a screenshot of that page where you are getting empty array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print_r($_GET)` is not querying / getting anything. You need to specify what `$_GET` is looking for.

In your case, your URL has the `token` and `tokenid` parameters. So you would need to `$_GET['token'];` and `$_GET['tokenid'];`

Comment: Friend i alredy did it but $_GET['token']; and $_GET['tokenid'] it echo nothing..thanks

Comment: Is that URL a string or is that the actual link to the page you would be currently on?

Comment: yes i am currently on that actual link page...on Password reset page where i am asking for new password to update password

Comment: @Satish can you share the code you used, so I can see if I can help you then?

Comment: i am sending this link by email. i am currently on inc_resetPassword.php page

Comment: I understand, but what is your PHP code context? Where did you throw `$_GET` to get the URL params, and what do you mean by `parameters(...)`

Comment: ohh.ok bro i understood what u trying to say me..actually i was on wrong page where i trying to get url parameters...now it solve.thanks a lot!!

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help